# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix when using two different layouts in a single layout file

Tags: android

When I compile my code there is a error in layout file  error in code:

> Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

How can I resolve it?  I'm using two different layouts in a single layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mypackage"
    xmlns:bm="com.mypackage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblUnabletoProceed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblWelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblYouraccountbalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNoRecentTransactions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLastTransactions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTransactionDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblInquiriesNTransactions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAgAppHelperMethods"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCustomAgAppHelperMethods"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mypackage"
        xmlns:bm="com.mypackage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <com.mypackage.controls.Carousel
            android:id="@+id/carousel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="206dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.92"
            android:animationDuration="200"
            pj:Items="@array/entries"
            pj:SelectedItem="0"
            pj:UseReflection="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.mypackage.SatelliteMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        sat:closeOnClick="true"
        sat:expandDuration="500"
        sat:mainImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        sat:satelliteDistance="170dp"
        sat:totalSpacingDegree="90" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why pj and bm, which seem to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

ur trying to add menu button it seems,the error is in

```
<com.mypackage.SatelliteMenu...need not to add like this
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend,

```
          viewing your layout code,I think problem is that you have not include namespace in your root element which you add in LinearLayout child element;"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mypackage"
```

Add this to your root element and looking to your code ,I think you are also using satelite menu lib,which also need namespace to included in your root element.